# How to differentiate between headers and static text in iOS 13 with XCTest UI Tests

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest

Running on iOS 13 using the latest versions of Xcode 11, I can't find a way to differentiate between headers and static text in XCTest UI tests.

If I use Xcode 11 but run on iOS 12, I'm still able to find views with the `.header` trait by filtering by `.other` element types with XCTest, but on iOS 13 views with the `.header` trait are now just identified by the `.staticText` element type with XCTest, even if you don't set the `.staticText` accessibility trait in the app.

This poses a problem for us because we use this to make sure that we're remembering to set the header traits properly on views for accessibility, as well as to be able to make sure we're looking at the right screen in tests.

Admittedly, only being able to find headers by `.other` isn't great but at least it was some way of differentiating headers from regular text.

Here's some sample code to explain:

```
// ViewController.swift

headerLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true // headerLabel is just a UILabel IBOutlet
headerLabel.accessibilityTraits = [.header]
headerLabel.text = "My Header"

// ViewControllerTests.swift

XCTAssertTrue(XCUIApplication().otherElements["My Header"].firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 30)) // This fails on iOS 13 but works on iOS 12 :(
XCTAssertTrue(XCUIApplication().staticTexts["My Header"].firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 30)) // This fails on iOS 12 but works on iOS 13...
```

If you `po XCUIApplication()` in Xcode you can see that on iOS 13, the header is now just a `staticText` same as every other label.

I've tried combining different accessibilityTraits (since you can have more than one), like:

```
headerLabel.accessibilityTraits = [.header, .staticText]
```

But that doesn't help.

Comment: Even more annoyingly, table section headers are still `.other`...

Comment: This seems like a bug in XCUI to me, if I completely hide the label from accessibility it still shows up in XCUI even though it's not meant to.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after a couple of days of investigating we have a workaround. Unfortunately it uses a private API, but we're not too worried since it's for tests and is better than any other workaround we've tried so far.

Using a private API, it is possible to figure out the underlying `UIAccessibilityTraits` of the view that an `XCUIElement` represents:

```
var underlyingAccessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
    guard let rawValue = value(forKey: "traits") as? UInt64 else { return [] }
    return UIAccessibilityTraits(rawValue: rawValue)
}
```

Now that we have the traits, we can query them same as any other `OptionSet`:

```
element.underlyingAccessibilityTraits.contains(.header)
```

And we can use that to build our own query, rather than using `XCUIElementQuery`:

```
let allElementsMatchingID = XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .any).matching(.any, identifier: id) // id is an optional string as an ID, like when using `XCUIApplication().otherElements[id]`
let allHeaders = allElementsMatchingID.allElementsBoundByAccessibilityElement.filter { $0.underlyingAccessibilityTraits.contains(.header) }
let element = allHeaders[index] // index is an int, like when using `element(boundBy: 0`
```

A downside to this (other than having to use a private API) is that unlike regular `XCUIElementQuery`s, this will crash if the index is out of bounds, but if you're always expecting the element to exist then that's not such a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a prefix to your header's `accessibilityIdentifier` to differentiate it from the static text like:

```
myHeader.accessibilityIdentifier = "Header" + title
```

and just use the same as before for your static text

```
myLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = title
```

Comment: Yeah that's what we were thinking too, except we make a framework that wraps XCUI and has a `Header` element that references headers by `.other` so the query to get the element will fail for anyone using the framework because it's `staticText`. This is the framework for reference: https://github.com/theappbusiness/TABTestKit